# Parsing xml with php from LOC

Tags: php, xml

I'm somewhat new to XML, and I'm trying to figure out how to parse an LOC API file.

So far, I've got:

```
$url = "http://lx2.loc.gov:210/lcdb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=bath.isbn=[0072424346]&maximumRecords=1&recordSchema=mods";

$string = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
```

I'm not getting any information stored at the point when I'm creating a `SimpleXMLElement` object, I've used `var_dump($xml)`,

getting: `object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }`

Which is an empty container, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you debugged the returned `$string`?